# Merging 2 tables with some overlapping primary keys Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to merge multiple tables together and i am worried about the primary key getting in the way, and also how it responds to each situation.

lets say I have 2 tables (same schema) but some entries in each table have the same primary key. What will happen when I try and merge these 2 tables together? Will I get an error, will it only accept one row into the merge?

What about the same idea but for a view or materialized view? How does the overlapping primary key get handled?

Anything in my tables that have the same primary key is a perfect duplicate so I would ultimately like to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a clear case for

```
INSERT INTO table1
   SELECT * FROM table2
ON CONFLICT (pk_column) DO NOTHING;
```

Then all the duplicates get discarded, and only the remaining rows will be inserted.